# how to pass variable on commands.getstatusoutput in python

Tags: python, unix, admin

Can someone help me how to pass variable in `commands.getstatusoutput`

I am trying to run below program to get information from remote server.

```
import os
import commands
ServerName = raw_input('Enter the Server name : ')
status, output = commands.getstatusoutput("rosh -l admin -n %ServerName uname")
print output
```

But when executing the program, ServerName is not getting replaced with hostname which which am entering in the terminal.

Comment: `getstatusoutput` accept regular python string objects. So you can use any of the existing string interpolation techniques to place the `ServerName` to the original string. for eg: `"rosh -l admin -n %s uname" % ServerName` **OR** f-strings `f"rosh -l admin -n {ServerName} uname"` **OR** the string `format` function `"rosh -l admin -n {}" uname".format(ServerName)`

Comment: @AbdulNiyasPM f-strings don't exist before Python 3.6. This code is for Python 2. The `commands` module doesn't exist in Python 3. That module just provides wrapper functions for `os.popen`, and it's much better to use the `subprocess` module than `os.popen`.

Comment: Great.. That resolved my issue. rosh -l admin -n %s uname" % ServerName worked for me.

Comment: could you please let me know how to pass one more variable in the same command? 
for eg : "rosh -l admin -n %s uname" % ServerName, 
In above comamnd, i want to read uname as user input and pass to the script as veriable.

"rosh -l admin -n %s uname" % ServerName,